# Finding same character in one string

Tags: java, string, indexof

I am creating a hangman game and I need the user to type a letter, once the letter is in it searches the string to check if it is there. The only problem is that it finds the first letter but not the second if there are two.  For example, if the word is roar it will return that the r is at 0, however it is at 3 too.

```
System.out.print("Guess: ");
        char c = s.next().charAt(0);
        if (newline.indexOf(c) >= 0) {
            index = newline.indexOf(c);

            System.out.println(newline.indexOf(c));
            System.out.println("Correct Guess!!");

            indexarray[x] = index;
            correctguesses[x] = c;
            count++;
```

Comment: Just loop through it and do what is necessary. Use the method toCharArray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just loop through it and do what is necessary. 
Use the method toCharArray to turn the string into a char array. Then use a for loop and go through that array.

Answer (score 1):

The `indexOf(int c)` method returns the index of the first occurrence of the `char`, from left to right. To find further occurrences you have to repeatedly call it, passing the index+1 of the last occurrence found, using `indexOf(int ch, int fromIndex)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    System.out.print("Guess: ");
    char c = s.next().charAt(0);
    int lastFind = 0; 
    while(newline.indexOf(c,lastFind) >= 0){
        if (newline.indexOf(c,lastFind) >= 0) {
            index = newline.indexOf(c,lastFind);

            System.out.println(newline.indexOf(c,lastFind));
            System.out.println("Correct Guess!!");

            indexarray[x] = index;
            correctguesses[x] = c;
            lastFind =index;
            count++;
         }
     }
```